# Use CTRL + D to exit and CTRL + L to cls in Powershell console

Tags: powershell, keyboard-shortcuts

I am trying to make

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> - exit Powershell console

and

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> - clear the screen

like in bash.

So far, I have seen that we can define

```
function ^D {exit}
```

but that means I have to do CTRL+D and then hit enter for it to work.

Also, it doesn't even let me define

```
function ^L {exit}
```

Is there anyway to add these key bindings in the default Powershell console?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

There is a new library [`PSReadline` for Powershell v3.0](https://github.com/PowerShell/psreadline) that emulates the GNU Bash tab completion and key bindings. Even <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> for reverse incremental search works. Exactly what I wanted.

Comment: This is very useful, however it does not let you press ctrl+d to exit the terminal.

Comment: You can get `CTRL` + `D` to exit with `Set-PSReadlineKeyHandler -Key Ctrl+d -Function DeleteCharOrExit` or by enabling the Emacs mode with `Set-PSReadlineOption -EditMode Emacs`

Comment: @0xced It seems that Set-PSReadlineOption is only available on PS 5.0. You can install that on Win 7SP1 onwards though. Not tried this yes, but it's not working on PS 4.0 certainly. Will try it when I upgrade at some point.

Comment: @0xced that should be its own and the accepted answer or added to this answer. Its not good when you have to read the comments to understand what's wrong with the top voted answer. :(

Answer (score 94):

Old question, but with PowerShell 5.1 and PowerShell Core 6.x and later:

```
Set-PSReadlineKeyHandler -Key ctrl+d -Function ViExit
```

Comment: This is the best solution by far, works right out of the box. Only if you want to persist the hotkey, you need add the above line to your `$Profile` file (use `Echo $Profile` to see its path). I had to create the `$Profile` directory and file in Notepad manually, but I am sure some PowerShell wizard can come up with a neat one-liner to do it all in one command..

Comment: You can just simply type `notepad $profile` to open the `$profile` file.

Comment: Keep in mind that `ViExit` exits terminal whether there is text in the command line or there isn't any. So, it doesn't work _like in bash_. If you want it to work like in bash, then stick with `DeleteCharOrExit` from @0xced comment.

Comment: @Glenn Neither `Set-PSReadlineKeyHandler` nor `ViExit` are recognized on my PSv5.1 :(

Comment: @SebMa I have PS 5.1.17763.1852 from Windows 10 LTSC, which is probably the oldest Windows version still supported, and this answer works.

Answer (score 17):

The keybindings are controlled by PSReadLine. PSReadLine's default edit mode is Windows style, where Ctrl-D is unbound.

Set your edit mode to Emacs

```
Set-PSReadlineOption -EditMode Emacs
```

or bound the key

```
Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler -Key 'Ctrl+d' -Function DeleteCharOrExit
```

Comment: Supports `-EditMode Vi` as well.

Comment: Thank you. This is actually the best answer, considering that those of us who want this feature are used to Bash or other Emacs-mode terminals. For those who have no idea where to put this command (like me a minute ago) you can create a bashrc-like file at the location shown by `$profile`, but you will have to open PS as Administrator and issue `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned` to make it work.

Answer (score 15):

If you don't mind relying on an external program, you could do the following with [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/):

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class ConsoleWindowClass
^L::SendInput , {Esc}cls{Enter}
^D::SendInput , {Esc}exit{Enter}
#IfWinActive
```

The above will work with the PowerShell or CMD console. Otherwise the only thing I can think of would be to work up some P/Invoke magic with `SetWindowsHookEx`.

**Edit:** Fixed AutoHotkey script to pass through the shortcut keys to other programs.

Comment: I would have preferred not doing it through external programs, but there doesn't seem to be any other way.

Answer (score 7):

There is also a PowerShell snapin called PSEventing which will allow you to do this (see the demo on the front page:

http://pseventing.codeplex.com/releases/view/66587

```
# clear screen in response to ctrl+L, unix style 
register-hotkeyevent "ctrl+L" -action { cls; write-host -nonewline (prompt) }
```

Comment: This makes PS dead slow under windows 8

Answer (score 6):

You can set your `PSReadline` to `emacs` mode, it will not only exit with `^D`, you will be able to go to beginning of line with `^A`, end of the line with `^E`

Include this in your profile:
`Set-PSReadlineOption -EditMode Emacs`

I'm using `cmder` which uses `ConEmu`, find `profile.ps1` with `<appdir>/vendor/` for that case and you can add into that file.

Otherwise you can add to default locations where `powershell` loads it. [One of tutorials HERE.](https://www.howtogeek.com/50236/customizing-your-powershell-profile/)

Answer (score 1):

Powrshell 5.x and 7.x

```
notepad $PROFILE
```

put lines below:

```
Set-PSReadlineKeyHandler -Key ctrl+d -Function ViExit
Set-PSReadlineKeyHandler -Key ctrl+l -Function ClearScreen
```

reload $PROFILE

```
. $PROFILE
```

Comment: straight to the point and also the only one that mentions `ClearScreen`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

2024 update

In Windows Terminal you can set Command line for PowerShell profile

```
pwsh -NoExit -Command "Set-PSReadlineKeyHandler -Key ctrl+d -Function ViExit"
```

That way you don't have to create profile or change execution policies.
Windows Terminal will close the tab automatically if you have Profile termination behaviour set to Automatic (default).