# sbt clear screen command

Tags: scala, sbt

I am learning `sbt` build tool. I use interpreted `sbt`. I run lot of commands and get lot of output which clutters up the screen.

The question is any command for clear screen for `sbt` interpretive console , like `cls` in DOS shell or `clear` in bash

My googling skill did not helped

update : i am using `console2` with `windows power shell`

Comment: What OS and what terminal are you using?

Comment: Ctrl+L works in linux.

Comment: updated with terminal used

Answer (score 47):

In bash you should be able to use Ctrl+L, on OSX you can also use Cmd+K.

Comment: i am using DOS Power Shell with console2

Comment: Maybe this post helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8360215/use-ctrl-d-to-exit-and-ctrl-l-to-cls-in-powershell-console

Comment: Ctrl+L clean the view, so you still will have the scroll dirty. Scroll up and all is there.

Answer (score 10):

This specifically helps when you're doing something in continuous mode, ala `compile:

```
maxErrors := 5
triggeredMessage := Watched.clearWhenTriggered
```

This works as of 0.13.7.  The second line clears the screen before each command runs.  The first line limits the number of errors.  With this config, you only ever have one screen full of errors to work through.  Obviously could adjust maxErrors depending on your sbt window.

Answer (score 4):

Sbt will load `~/.sbt/1.0/build.sbt` as global settings.

```
commands += Command.command("cls") { state =>
  print("\033c")
  state
}
```

Then you can run any commands with cls. For example:

- `~;cls;compile`
- `~;cls;testOnly`